# What should I do for sign in to google play games

Tags: android, google-play-games

What should I do for sign in to [google play games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin) , I read previous document carefully but I don't understand what google means about that.

Do I should sign in firstly by `DEFAULT_SIGN_IN` or `DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN`

I did `DEFAULT_SIGN_IN` in below :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 100);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            //I got user data successfully but I want login by google play games , can someone guide me next step ?
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Log.w("aaa","E " + e.getMessage() + " | " + e.getStatusCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask them (Google) they seem to uppsedtning everyone.

Comment: I think you should consider using DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN if you want to sign in with Google Play games. I guess Default sign in is for Google account sign in.

Comment: I tried replace `DEFAULT_SIGN_IN` to `DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN` but got error `2019-09-16 20:01:20.737 183897-183897/com.test.gamelogin W/aaa: E 12501:  | 12501`

Comment: I want to be honest , I was trying do login by google play games almost 1 month ago and I posted many questions on different platforms but unfortunate get same result everytime (no carefully answer).